# Is it possible to pass a parameter to an oozie workflow to control it?

Tags: hadoop, sqoop, oozie

I have an Oozie workflow that as it first step must import a number of tables using sqoop. Unfortunately sometimes there are restrictions on how much I can import on a given run. Is it possible to pass a parameter either from the CLI or in the properties file that tell which of the six files to import?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Workflow definitions can be parameterized.

- https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.3.1/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a4_Parameterization_of_Workflows
- Sqoop action: https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.3.1/DG_SqoopActionExtension.html

Comment: Thanks! I think this will make it.